# Facebook Graph API - Object Insights Returning No Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-insights

I am getting a response with an empty data array for most if not all of the object insight Facebook API calls.  I am requesting the following permissions when logging in: read_insights, publish_pages, manage_pages.

some requests I am trying to make include: page_views_total, page_impressions, page_fans

```
FB.api(
      "/1493689654199431/insights/page_impressions/lifetime",
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      }
  );
```

Response example:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1493689654199431/insights/page_impressions/lifetime?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAGNO4tT95osm9KIaLlsoxoWPyk7g4J6m3iBwa5ZArxGEZBbeIpILExuTZAC6KFRHfCuccbsOCCQLmRZCItZAAmTs3PXzueCCJ0CVjr6UBB3gZCfClQeeI1PbHZCnJVqZBPHf00Vl6U4Lj6B1FpMhZAqUSdXNvcPDWlAZDZD&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1462194002&until=1462453202",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1493689654199431/insights/page_impressions/lifetime?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAGNO4tT95osm9KIaLlsoxoWPyk7g4J6m3iBwa5ZArxGEZBbeIpILExuTZAC6KFRHfCuccbsOCCQLmRZCItZAAmTs3PXzueCCJ0CVjr6UBB3gZCfClQeeI1PbHZCnJVqZBPHf00Vl6U4Lj6B1FpMhZAqUSdXNvcPDWlAZDZD&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1462712402&until=1462971602"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript SDK uses a User Token by default, you need to get and use a Page token for Page Insights. You get a Page Token with the `/me/accounts` endpoint, and this is how you can use it:

```
FB.api(
    "/1493689654199431/insights/page_impressions/lifetime",
    {access_token: pageToken},
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
);
```

You can debug your Page Token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response luschn, however I tried this and still getting the same empty data array.

Comment: did you debug the response? i mean, not in the if-block, but at the beginning of the callback.

Comment: also, debug your page token and make sure it really is a page token and it really includes the read_insights permission (other permissions are not neccessary).

Comment: i added a link to the token debugger

Comment: I grabbed the pageToken from the response before it hits the page_imressions call and put it in the debugger and I see all of the permissions including read_insights

Comment: page_fans is returning data but page_views_total and page_impressions still returning empty data array

Comment: is the page id visible in the debugger? only then it is a page token.

Comment: yes there is a Profile ID i am assuming this is the page ID?

Comment: in the token debugger

Comment: and in the call back I am using the page ID i get from the response to make the call so yeah its there as well

Comment: ok, then i assume the endpoint just does not exist or there are no values...if you think there should be, you could file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The reason being, page_impressions takes only three values for period = day, week, days_28.

I tried with

```
FB.api('/page-id/insights/page_impressions/days_28',{access_token: page-access-token}, function(response){
    console.log('page impressions',response);
})
```

and got data.

Had the same issue of empty data, it got resolved